# I need a help in displaying the String in next line

Tags: java

I am trying to frame the error details of my API in to  Mail Body.
In first line I would like to mention the API and in next line I would need to  put the error details. But the mail body come all together like below:

```
WEATHER_POST is Failing and the Error details are below.. { "FaultId": "Invalid 
method type found in Request.", "fault": "FAULT_INVALID_METHOD_TYPE_IN_REQUEST" 
}BILLS_API is Failing and the Error details are below.. 
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: 158cd00a- 
4942-4771-b54c-ed3da0f15a6c"}
```

But i would like to see the message as like below

```
WEATHER_POST is Failing and the Error details are below..

{ "FaultId": "Invalid 
method type found in Request.", "fault":     "FAULT_INVALID_METHOD_TYPE_IN_REQUEST" 
}

BILLS_API is Failing and the Error details are below.. 


{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: 158cd00a- 
4942-4771-b54c-ed3da0f15a6c"}
```

Below is the code and i have list of beans where the api and error details are present

```
    StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();
    for (MessageDetails element : failureList) {

        message.append(element.getApi()+" is Failing and the Error details are below.. ");
        message.append(element.getBody());
    }   
    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("emailBody", message.toString());
```

Can any one please help?

Comment: is it a plain text mail or html mail? In the code you have put any formatting instructions, how do you expect it to format by itself.

Comment: Its just a plain text..it would be great if the API details come bold.

Comment: @RamKarlapudi Plain text emails cannot contain formatting. (That's what the "plain" means.) If you need bold, you need to use HTML email. Plain text allows only text, spaces and blank lines.

Comment: I need plain text with separate lines.

Comment: Just append newlines (`”\n”`)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt please attach MessageDetails class, failurelist composition (or a written example) and where you extract the json.

Comment: Who are you? You’re not the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Empirically, we can try doing a regex replacement on your input string.  The option below inserts two newlines whenever an opening or closing bracket is seen.

```
input = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\}.)|(?=\\{)", "\n\n");
```

Here is the output:

```
WEATHER_POST is Failing and the Error details are below.. 

{ "FaultId": "Invalid method type found in Request.", "fault": "FAULT_INVALID_METHOD_TYPE_IN_REQUEST}

BILLS_API is Failing and the Error details are below..

{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid8 access token: 158cd00a- 4942-4771-b54c-ed3da0f15a6c]"}
```

### Demo

Of course, this won't work well if you could have nested brackets in your input text.  But, we don't see this in your sample data.

**Edit:**

The above code is intended to be a blanket replacement on your entire message, so you might modify your exact code to this:

```
String output = message.toString();
output = output.replaceAll("(?<=\\}.)|(?=\\{)", "\n\n");
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
requestParams.put("emailBody", output.toString());
```

Comment: Hi Tim,Where i need to add this in my code ??                                                 
      input = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\}.)|(?=\\{)", "\n\n");

Comment: @RamKarlapudi My code is working in the demo.  You either copied wrongly, or your actual code is something other than what you showed us above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below for where you need to have a line break.

```
buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add newlines `"\n"` to the Strings you're appending to the buffer:

```
StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();
for (MessageDetails element : failureList) {

    message.append(element.getApi()+" is Failing and the Error details are below.. \n\n");
    message.append(element.getBody()+"\n\n");
}   
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
requestParams.put("emailBody", message.toString());
```

Comment: The body itself also needs modifying

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think that is just text wrapping. Look at the last lines betw. the curlies, they are identical.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants an extra couple of lines in here `}BILLS_API`